# How can I start my webpage and test it with Selenium

Tags: selenium, junit

I installed Selenium on my local machine where Spring Boot with PostgresSQL is running, too.
Now I want to run an unit test with Selenium.
As soon as I use google.com as a test source, everything works as expected but when I want to test my webpage it cannot be opened.

Here is my class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LoginWebsiteTest {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void seleniumLoginWebsiteTest() {
        driver.get("http://localhost:9000/login");
        ....
```

As we can see my webpage is running on port 9000 but as soon as Google Chrome is automatically started the webpage cannot be displayed.

What do I miss here exactly?

If someone could help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

I always thought that it uses the application.properties to load the correct port and everything else. What I had to do was:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class LoginWebsiteTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    private static WebDriver driver;
    ...
    driver.get("http://localhost:" + port + "/login");
```

It chooses any port and this port has to be used for my website!